# Vue TypeScript type props from extended component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

We have a base `Interactive` component, which by design is supposed to be the base for other components to consume and add their own spin on. For example, the `Button` component renders the `Interactive` as a basis, and extends functionality as well as adding styles.

As such, all the props from the `props` definition of the `Interactive` component should be added as props on the parent `Button`.

Previously we implemented this as such:

```js
{
  props: {
    ...Interactive.props,
    aCustomProp: {/* ... */}
}
```

Since we are converting to TypeScript, this is not valid Vue, and although works seems like was a bad implementation and "hacky". Lesson learned there. We want to avoid the usage of mixins as personal preference of the team, and ideally would like to not duplicate prop definition in each component that uses the `Interactive` child.

I think `extends: Interactive` might be the solution, however we end up in a position where `props.disabled` can not be inferred by TypeScript.

Essentially, how I can extend a component and have TS infer its props?

**Interactive.vue**

```js
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    disabled: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    to: { type: String, required: false, default: null }
  }
});
```

**Button.vue**

```js
import Interactive from './Interactive.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    primary: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
  },
  extends: Interactive,
  setup(props) {
    if (props.disabled) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
});
```

The above gives the error `Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ name: string; loading: boolean; } & {}>'`

Comment: It's `import Interactive from './Interactive.vue'`, the extension matters, could be the problem here. I don't see the problem, props are supposed to be inherited from `extends`. Is the problem in IDE or project build? "this is not valid Vue" - I don't see much problems with this either.

Comment: Apologies, that’s a typo since I wrote all the code inside SO for demo purposes, since the real components are more complicated. Will update to provide extension since all my component imports have the extensions

Comment: The problem occurs in build, and if I extract the component script to a `.ts` extension file happens there too. Inside a Vue SFC there are no errors in VSCode, which leads me to believe Vetur is interfering in some way

Comment: There should be `<script lang="ts">`, it's not shown. It's totally possible that IDE doesn't have this problem because every tool that involves TS works differently in some way. You may want to try to use the same TS version in the project as in Vetur for starters. What is TS version btw? If it's not recent, it could be upgraded.

Comment: There is a `lang="ts"` on the script tag, and the version is `4.4.5` for both VSCode and project

Comment: Make sure that it's true for Vetur too, I'm not sure if it's possible that it uses its own version, https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/682

Answer (score 0):

For anyone discovering this now, the problem still persists in Vue3. The way we work around it, and this works for both Vue2 and Vue3 is to use a `sharedProps` definition of some kind.

If using Vue3 script setup then that would be:

```
export interface SharedProps {
  prop1: string
}

// --

import type { SharedProps } from './path/to/props';

const props = defineProps<SharedProps & { prop2: number }>();
```

If using the object syntax then it would be this:

```
export const sharedProps = {
  prop1: { type: String, default: '', },
  // ...
}

// --

import { sharedProps } from './path/to/props';

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    ...sharedProps,
    prop2: { type: number, default: 0 },
});
```

Unfortunately they're not interchangeable as far as I can tell, unless you pass the shared props to `defineProps()` as a param instead of the generic.

There might be a way of creating a TS util to extract the type from the object definition though.